# query multiple posts by id using a string parameter, not array()

Tags: query-posts

I'm looking for a way to query posts by id, and using a string as a parameter, instead of an array. Like this:

query_posts('p=153');

But I need to get multiple posts. For example with ID 153 and 154. How would I do that with a string as a parameter?

The reason that I'm using a string is because I'm generating that string with javascript and if I would do it otherwise it will get super complicated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the string to an array using the [php explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). So if you used a comma as your delimiter, you could pass the string   `'153,154,87'` and that would and then use the explode function to convert it to

```
array(
[0]=>'153'
[1]=>'154'
[2]=>'87'
)
```

If you want to keep the `p=` you could use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) etc.